# How to create images using JavaScript/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-processing, discord

[image: User stats by a bot in Discord]

How can I create something like a profile card where I will modify some text and colors and then make it an image? I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to use in this case is SVG.  You're combining data with a variety of elements and then putting them all together.  SVG is much like HTML, but with a tighter focus on the image itself.  You can combine raster elements, your data, and vector elements, to make the final image.  From there you can either use this image directly or render it to a PNG.

I strongly recommend leaving it in SVG if at all possible, to preserve the text nature of a lot of this data.  Not everyone can see the screen.  If you burn text into a raster image, screen readers won't be able to read it.